# div has style of 100vh with inner scroll so I need toggle class for each **section-wrapper** when **each one of it in viewport during the scroll**

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular9, ng-bootstrap

```
<div class="tables-section">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let .. of ..">
    <div class="section-wrapper">
      <h3>{{section.title}}</h3>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let .. of ...">
        <div class="table-content">
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr *ngIf=".. > ..">
                <th scope="col" class="text-light form-title">{{..}}</th>
                <ng-container>
                  <th *ngFor="let .. of .." scope="col">
                    <div>
                      {{..}}
                    </div>
                  </th>
                </ng-container>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody ..[![enter image description here][1]][1] [..]=".."></tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

kindly, I have **tables-section** which do looping for **section-wrapper** and this is has style of 100vh (view height of screen) with inner scroll so I need toggle class for each **section-wrapper** when **each one of it in viewport during the scroll**  **(Angular 9)**
Thanks in advance ;)

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you need exactly but it seems like you might find [intersection observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) useful.

Comment: Thank You , I think it will help me I was searching about the inner scroll inside area that has specific height and it includes sections so I want for example console message  when the scroll arrived to each section